# Android Push Notification not opening my activity with webview

Tags: android, push-notification, android-webview

I created a push notifications app following this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

It works and when I get the notification, I can open a website. However, am I able to combine the webview layout with this push notifications app? I feel like it has to be possible because the email notifications work in that way.

Here is my code which handles the notification I receive:

```
private void handleData(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String app_name = (String) context.getText(R.string.app_name);
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_chat, app_name + ": " + message, 0);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, -1, new Intent(context, webviewactivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); // 
    notification.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, app_name, message, pendingIntent); //
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

However, the HomeActivity which is linked to the main.xml is just a button to register and unregister your device for receiving the notifications. I created another file, webviewactivity.xml under layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:id="@+id/webview"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 />
```

and I created the following activity, webviewactivity

```
public class BHWebView extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bhwebview_activity);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.badgerherald.com");
    }
}
```

For some reason though when I click my notification it opens the home activity, not the webview activity.

Comment: Hi, I am new to android app, i want to know is a webview app good in terms of usability of users (for a e-commerce website ) ? I have a e-commerce website, i will convert it into webview android app, then will ii be able to send pushnotification to my app users ?
Please help me with this

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal, a webview is horrible. There are alot of bugs and missing features. I was not even able to open PDF files.

Comment: The name of the question is a bit misleading, I thought it m you meant Chrome push notifications on Android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the notification open your WebView app instead: send a PendingIntent, as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

Comment: So the WebView app would actually have to be a separate app (different project folder in Eclipse) from the pushnotifications app? If so, how do you import the WebView app into the pushnotifications app?

Comment: No, you can put the WebView in an Activity in the same app.

Comment: Alright. So I'm basing my WebView off of this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html. But I'm a little confused as to how to integrate the WebView activity. Would I make a new activity for the WebView in the pushnotifications? Right now the main.xml for the pushnotifications is a layout that just registers and shows the registration ID of the device. When I tried to copy the WebView into it, I got some error (forgot the exact error, but I can look it up and post it). Thanks

Comment: The notification has one view, but launches the WebView activity, which is separate.

Comment: @Kev: Can you Please help me by Describing Step by Step Process to implement push Notification in webview.

I am trying so much to implement but not succeed yet. Please help if you could , Waiting for your  reply.  Thanks in advance

Comment: @chiragNandwani Hey man, I honestly can't really remember because this was almost two years ago. I'm fairly positive I have my old code and I can take a look. I'd have to refresh myself. I'm not sure if you're allowed to on stackoverflow, but if you leave your email I can email you in a day or two after I refresh myself. Oterwise this is the tutorial I used. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

Comment: @Kev: Ok, Then It's my email address: "er.chiragnagpal@gmail.com". Waiting for your rply and hope so you will help me in this part . Thanks in advance.

Comment: @YusufX, thats unfair to share the infos only via e-mail and not with us all on stackoverflow

Comment: @Black you can take that up with Kevin.

Comment: I'm also very interested in this example could you share it with me too? @Kev

Comment: @chiragNandwani maybe you could send it per email to me too? chagai95@gmail.com