# How to allow notification permission in Android WebView on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, webview

I am using Android Studio, I created one `WebView` app, this app contain website, this website will receive notification alert with sound, so I need to that sound.

Normally, when we opening any website in chrome or any browser, there will ask notification permission, but here, how to allow that?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);//setting wide view
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);//setting default zoomed out view
    webView.setInitialScale(1);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("https://grillizuae.com");

    //webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Desktop");

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

could that be useful to you?

[Notifications API Links](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API)

[Allow notifications Android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69078346/allow-notifications-android-webview)

Hopefuly you can make it work from one of those example